# How to pass the javascript value while submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to asp.net mvc4. I want to pass the java script value when submitting the form. I want to pass the value of random field which is in javascript along with the text box values. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
This is my Javascript code for generating and validating the captcha:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var captchastring = '';
    function getCaptcha() {
        var chars = "0Aa1Bb2Cc3Dd4Ee5Ff6Gg7Hh8Ii9Jj0Kk1Ll2Mm3Nn4Oo5Pp6Qq7Rr8Ss9Tt0Uu1Vv2Ww3Xx4Yy5Zz";
        var string_length = 7;
        captchastring = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
            var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            captchastring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
        }
        document.getElementById("randomfield").innerHTML = captchastring;
        document.getElementById("forgot_password_form").submit();
    }

    function validation() {
        var text2 = document.getElementById("txtcode").value;
        if (text2 == captchastring) {

            var email = document.getElementById("UserEmail").value;

            x = document.getElementById("demo");
            // Find the element

            x.innerHTML = "valid";
            x.style.color = "#ff0000";

        }
        else {

            x = document.getElementById("demo");  // Find the element
            x.innerHTML = "Invalid Captcha. Try again";
            x.style.color = "#ff0000";
            return false;
        }
    }

 </script>
```

Code for submiting form:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Forgotpassword", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="forgot_password_form"})) 
    {        
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserEmail, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
<input type="text" name="txtcaptcha" id="txtcaptchaid"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter code here" />
    <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" style="float: right; width:30%;" value="Reset Password" onclick="validation()" /> <p id="demo"> </p>  
    }
```

Comment: I want to pass the java script value when submitting the form?? what kind of value you want to pass?
You can add Hidden Input Fields with Javascript

Comment: yes it is working fine.